# Electron error 'The procedure entry point DiscardVirtualMemory could not be locted in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll'

Tags: electron, electron-build

Saludos tengo una aplicación en Electron version 25.3.0 al empaquetarlo con el electron-builder con este comando '$ electron-packager . migracion-agenda-dia --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --out=dist/ --overwrite', este comando me genera un empaquetdo con un archivo .exe, al intentar ejecutar este .exe en windows server 2008 R2 me salta el error 'The procedure entry point DiscardVirtualMemory could not be locted in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll', ya estuve investigando pero no doy con la solución, me podrían ayudar..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Electron no funciona en versiones de windows antiguas a 2018.
revisa la documentación.

ya me paso, por eso lo menciono

mas informacion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvtQiErSPyc

Comment: que alternativa podría realizar, porque me funciona correctamente para los windows standar pero no para los windows server, he estado probando en windows server 2008 y 2012 pero obtengo el mismo error

Comment: actualiza a windows server 2019, el problema es de windows y solo eso, no hay forma de que funcione en equipos viejos electron es asi, esta echo para las nuevas tecnologias si me dices 2012 son 11 años atras es demaciado obsoleto

Answer (score 0):

Después de hacer una jornada de prueba manual con cada versión de electron,la versión 22.0.0 es compatible para estos sistemas operativos de windows server